# Reload /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: pam, limits

I would like to:

- make a soft 64GB limit for resident memory (so inexperienced users will get their run-amok processes killed, but experienced users can raise the limit for memory hungry processes)
- raise the hard limit for nofile, but keep the soft limit at 1024 (so if a certain program needs more filehandles, the user can grant them, but run-amok programs will not get them).

As far as I can see, I should be able to do that in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (or in `/etc/security/limits.d/*`):

```
*        soft    rss             64000000
*        hard    nofile          50000
*        soft    nofile          1024
```

I can, however, not find a way reload these values with out rebooting. I have read that the values are reloaded when logging in; it works when I do `su - user` but it does not work through `ssh user@localhost`.

I have the pam_limits.so in /etc/pam.d:

```
/etc/pam.d/login:session    required   pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    required     pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/su:session    required   pam_limits.so
```

I have PAM in sshd_config:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:UsePAM yes
```

I know I can set the values using `ulimit` and `sysctl`, but I would like to test that the `/etc/security/limits.conf` is doing the right thing without rebooting.

How can I make sure that the values are being set when people login using ssh without rebooting?

Comment: Do you have "UsePAM no" in sshd_config? That may cause the problem.

Comment: My /etc/ssh/sshd_config has `UsePAM yes`. Good guess, though.

Comment: Can you try restarting the SSH daemon and then see if users sees the new limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grrr....

`UseLogin` is not needed.

`UsePAM yes` is needed.

A restart of `sshd` is only needed if `UsePAM` was changed from no to yes.

Disabling my own `~/.ssh/config` was needed very much!

I had `Control`* statements in my `~/.ssh/config` which re-used the ssh channel and thus I would not discover the change.

Thanks to Samed Beyribey and quanta, whose help gave me the idea to run `ssh -vv` which gives very different output when you have `Control`* statements.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that the values are reloaded when logging in; it works
>   when I do `su - user` but it does not work through `ssh
>   user@localhost`.

The reason is: by default, SSH opening a non-login shell, so limits is not being applied.

To make it uses a login shell, edit your `sshd_config` file and uncomment/change `#UseLogin no` to `UseLogin yes`:

```
gentoo ~ # grep UseLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
#UseLogin no
gentoo ~ # sed -i.bak 's/#UseLogin no/UseLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
gentoo ~ # grep UseLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
UseLogin yes
```

Reload the `sshd` and try again.

Source: http://znx.no/2011/01/ssh-and-limits/